# What options for replacing a leaking soil pipe?

Tags: sewer

There are tree roots growing in the soil pipe leading from my home to the street.  (The pipe is about 75 feet long.)  When it is time to repair or replace the soil pipe, what are the options and their pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

**Option's include but are not limited to**

1. cured in place, where the pipe is lined with a resin soaked material and hardens in place. I'm not familiar with it but I've heard it works well.
2. Pipe bursting, I did this at my house and got them to pull a 1" copper line with the waste line upgrading both services at the same time. I don't know how far they can pull. Some machines will obviously be better than others. I watched a civic project and they pulled a (approximately 20' diameter pipe) nearly half a mile.
3. Trenching, is the simplest method but will require a massive swath of ground to be excavated. For safety shoring needs to be erected if anyone is working in the trench. If you find anyone willing to go in a 8' trench without proper shoring, I wouldn't use them.

It boils down to cost vs. inconvenience vs. quality. Also what each method is capable of doing. My plumber had pipe burst done for a customer of his. 50' under an award winning garden. In that case trenching was not an option.